# Passing PHP Array to XSL

Tags: php, arrays, xslt

My Array (`$arr`) is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [partners_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [partners_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [partners_id] => 6
        )
)
```

I'm passing PHP Array using

```
$this->xsl->setParameter('','my_arr',$arr);
```

Now I want to use all its elements in XSL, and check which ids are coming in `partners_id`. Based on those ids, I want to show xml pages

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('dashboard.h1.xml')/*"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('dashboard.h2.xml')/*"/>
```

etc.

can anyone guide?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no no its XSL not XLS :(

Comment: @Let'sCode you are mixing concepts...the OP is asking about XSL, and not XLS

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking. What is the content of the variable you are passing? What is not working? What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: @MathiasMüller thanks for your comment, i've an array in php like (arr[0]['id']=1,arr[1]['id']=2) etc im passing it XSL using setParameter as mentioned above, now i wana get all ids of arrays in XSL and show content on the bases of that ids..

Comment: @MathiasMüller im sorry if its something stupid, im actually working at XSL first time..

Comment: Please edit your post and include more PHP code and your XSLT stylesheet - and explain _what exactly_ is not working.

Comment: @MathiasMüller is it useful now?